# Adding text before an aligned paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, alignment

How do I add text before I align a paragraph?

For example, I want a paragraph that looks something like this

```
Aside:  Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

I currently have the following command

```
\newcommand{\aside}[1]{
     \underline{Aside}:\par
     \begingroup
     \leftskip4em
     \rightskip\leftskip
     {#1}
     \par
}
```

but the paragraph skips a line after the "Aside:". Is there perhaps a simpler command out there that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of the command `aside` with `par` following word "aside" require that following text start in new line. See, if the following work around gives what you like to have:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\aside}[1]{\par\medskip\noindent%
     \underline{Aside}:\hfill
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-8em\relax}
        #1
     \end{minipage}\hspace{4em}\mbox{}\par\medskip
                        }

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\aside{Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

Edit: Now is upčoaded correct image and code. sorry for the nise.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list` environment with suitable parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\aside}[1]{
    \begin{list}
    {\underline{Aside:}\hfill}
    {
        \labelsep=0pt
        \labelwidth=4em
        \leftmargin=\labelwidth
        \rightmargin=\labelwidth
    }
        \item #1
    \end{list}
}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

\aside{%
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum%
}

Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `enumitem`, it is simple to define a custom `description` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]

\begin{description}[labelwidth=3em, leftmargin= 4em, rightmargin=4em, itemindent=0pt, nosep, font=\normalfont]
\item[\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}\underline{Aside}:]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{description}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Five simple methods in no particular order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,tabularx,eqlist}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip1em\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3] % dummy text 

% method 1
\hangindent4em\makebox[4em][l]{Aside:}\lipsum[1][1-3]

% method 2
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}lL@{}}
Aside: & \lipsum[1][1-3]\\
\end{tabulary}

% method 3
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
Aside: & \lipsum[1][1-3]\\
\end{tabularx}


% method 4
\makebox[4em][l]{Aside:}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4em}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}


% method 5 
\begin{eqlist}
\item[Aside:] \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item[Longer label:] \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{eqlist}

\lipsum[1][1-3] % dummy text 

\end{document}
```